# Ansible group_vars in template module

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I want to copy file using jinja2 templating in ansible.

I have one file inside templates/file.j2 and inside that file I have one variable defined

```
fos.broker.host={{ fos.broker.host }}
```

Inside group_vars/stage I have the value of this variable as

```
fos.broker.host: 'api_vl.vlstage.fidor.de'
```

And finally I am deploying it via main.yml and it looks like.

```
---
- hosts: vlstage
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/vlstage

  tasks:
  - name: copy files to host
    template: src=templates/file.j2 dest=/opt/tomcat/lib/file.conf 
    backup=yes owner=zoaib group=zoaib
```

but when I run command `ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml -u zoaib`

I get below error:

```
TASK [copy files to host] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [s-vl-idl-app02.fidor.intern]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'fos' is undefined"}
```

any leads to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use dots in variable names. Dot notation is used to refer to dictionary keys.

Read [What Makes A Valid Variable Name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name):

> `foo-port`, `foo port`, `foo.port` and `12` are not valid variable names.

---

Although in reality, it is possible to use a variable with dots in their name and refer to its value it with the `vars` lookup plugin:

```
fos.broker.host={{ lookup('vars', 'fos.broker.host') }}
```